# Выборка из txt в bat файле

Tags: cmd, bat

Имеется текстовый файл, в котором хранится журнал обработанных файлов в следующем формате:

**Имя: kn-25.txt Дата: 02.01.2013 Время: 14:50**

Необходимо написать командный файл, с помощью которого сделать выборку из этого файла за заданный месяц (мм) и год (гггг) в файл result.txt. Сформированный файл упорядочить по дате обработки.

```
@echo off
chcp 1251 >nul
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Введіть початковий файл:  
set /p in_file=%~nx1
if not exist %in_file% goto end

del D:\result.txt
set /a count=0
set /a con=0
set /a min=101
set /p month=Введіть місяць: 
if [%month%] == [] goto end 
set /p year=Введіть рік: 
if [%year%] == [] goto end 
goto start

:start
if count equ 0 (
set /a con=0 
) else (
set /a con=0-!count!
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%in_file%) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-6" %%a in ("%%~i") do (
        for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%u in ("%%~d") do (
            if "%%v"=="%month%" if "%%w"=="%year%" (
                 set /a con=!con!+1 
                     if "%%u" leq "!min:~-2!" (
                         set /a min1=!min!-1
                         if "%%u" neq "!min1:~-2!" (
                            set /a count=!count!+1                    
                            echo !count!. %%i>>D:\result.txt
                    )
                )
            )       
        )   
    )
)

if %con% neq %count% (
set /a min=!min!+1
goto start
) else (
type D:\result.txt
echo 
@pause
endlocal
exit /B 
)

:end
echo Ви не ввели параметр!
echo   
@pause
endlocal
exit /B
```

Note: строки должны быть отсортированы по дате создания

**Пример:**

*Содержимое файла:*

Name: kn-25.txt Date: 07/03/2013 Time: 14:50

Name: kn-26.txt Date: 02/03/2013 Time: 23:50

Name: MyFil.txt Date: 03/08/2012 Time: 12:00

Name: ca-21.txt Date: 28/03/2013 Time: 01:00

Name: ca-25.txt Date: 01/30/2012 Time: 10:05

*Ввод:* 03.2013

*Вывод:*

Name: kn-26.txt Date: 02/03/2013 Time: 23:50

Name: kn-25.txt Date: 07/03/2013 Time: 14:50

Name: ca-21.txt Date: 28/03/2013 Time: 01:00

*Написал вот такой код, но при вводе 01.2012 получаю:*

1. Ім'я: ca-20.txt    Дата: 01.01.2012 Час: 09:00
2. Ім'я: ca-20.txt    Дата: 01.01.2012 Час: 09:00
3. Ім'я: ca-20.txt    Дата: 01.01.2012 Час: 09:00

*Что подскажете делать ?*

Comment: Я бы просто выдрал с помощью regexp-выражения строки нужной даты и поместил их в файл обработки (**for** + **findstr**). Во время вывода в этот файл ещё в начале строк приплюсовал бы дату в формате YYYYMMDD (строковые преобразования **"%~%"** ). Затем пересортировал бы файл обработки с удалением даты (**sort** + **for**).

Comment: таки ... powershell технологичнее.

Comment: Относительно ошибки к Вашему коду. Переменная **in_file** берёт указанное первым входным параметром имя файла и добавляет к нему путь. И скорее всего это путь того места, откуда был вызван батник. Значит проблема в том, что по указанному пути НЕТ файла с заданным именем.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Спасибо, уже решил проблему. Если интересно, вставлю код.

Comment: Вставьте, пожалуйста. Может кому пригодится эта архаика. Лучше в форме ответа, если это рабочий код.

Comment: @Daemon-5, все-таки помощь нужна. Отдредактировал вопрос.

Comment: А сортировки хватит только по дате, или ещё точнее надо, с учетом часов и минут?

Comment: @Daemon-5, только по дате.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема, скорее всего, в том, что обработка работает с одним и тем же параметром, без учета новых пустых данных входа.

Предлагаю такой код, как уже было описано в моих комментариях.

```
@set month=03
@set year=2013
@set in_file=1.txt



@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@for /f "tokens=1-6 skip=2" %%a in ('@find "%month%/%year%" %in_file%') do @(
@set d=%%d
@set d=%year%%month%!d:~0,2!
@echo.!d! %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f>>result0.txt

)

@for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('@sort result0.txt') do @echo.%%b>>result.txt
@del/q result0.txt>NUL

@endlocal
```